# How to List Files greater than particular timestamp?

Tags: linux, find, grep, ls

I have a directory in linux which has a list of log files where log files get auto generated if some job runs. Each log file gets appended with the timestamp like "JobName_TimeStamp"

**UPDATED:**

```
job_2014-05-28_15:05:26.log
job_2014-05-28_15:06:58.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:02.log
job_2014-05-28_15:07:57.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log

job1_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

I wanted to run a linux command to list all files greater than a particular timestamp?

For Example 1 : I will pass two parameters ,
If the **TimeStamp** given is "**2014-05-28_15:08:00**" and **Job Name** is "**job**"

I should get the list as

```
job_2014-05-28_15:08:01.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:09.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:10.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

Example 2 : I will pass two parameters ,
If the **TimeStamp** given is "**2014-05-28_15:08:11**" and **Job Name** is "**job1**"

I should get the list as

```
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:12.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:13.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:14.log
job1_2014-05-28_15:08:22.log
```

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command, which can easily be scripted, will do it for you:

```
 for i in $(ls *); do
           if [[ "job_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log" < "$i" ]]; then
                  echo $i
           fi
 done
```

EDIT:

Suppose you want to do this for just jobs called *myjob*, then modify the above as follows:

```
 for i in $(ls myjob*); do
           if [[ "myjob_2014-05-28_15:08:00.log" < "$i" ]]; then
                  echo $i
           fi
 done
```

Comment: Yes this works. Is there a way without using a loop?

Comment: Also i just want to know If the above code works if the files are in random order ?

Comment: @Kabilan yes, it works even even if they are in random order. And no, you cannot kill the *do* loop, you can just compactify the *if* statement by using, instead of *if Condition then Action fi*, *Condition && Action*.

Comment: there can be multiple jobs running thereby creating multiple log files also same job can be run many times. so Is it possible to pass the job name as well into that if loop  and check the condition ????

Comment: @Kabilan Can you pls explain?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example

Comment: u got my question Marius??

Comment: @Kabilan See my edit.

Comment: Yes Perfect that is wat i require :) Thanks a lot Marius :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple find command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name job1_\* -newer job1_2014-05-28_15:08:11.log
```

There are 2 assumptions in this example:

- mtime of log files correlates to timestamps in file names
- you can provide particular file name that is the lower bound for all wanted log files

Comment: Should anyone read, modify one of the files, its name will not be the same as its last access/modify time. The OP asked to order the files on the basis of the name, not access/modify/... time.